# Express framework and Promises - what to return from a route handler?

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I have been using the following promise-based template for my Express route handlers:

```
app.get('/accounts/:id', function(req, res) {

    AccountService.getAccount(req.params.id)
        .then(function(account) {
            res.send(account);
            //----- then must return a promise here -----
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            res.status(500).send({'message': error.toString()});
        });
});
```

While this code works perfectly fine, I am uncomfortable that the `onFulfilled` function is not returning a promise. This is required by the [Promise Specification](https://promisesaplus.com/): *then must return a promise*. Is there a better way to code this?

Comment: That statement doesn't apply here. You would have needed your then to return a promise ***if*** you were to assign the return value of `AccountService.getAccount` to something, like `promise2 = promise1.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);` Since you don't care about that you don't have to return anything from then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misinterpreted the spec.

> `then` must return a promise

You are confusing the return value of `then` with the return value of your *callback* to `then`. They are very different.

`then` must return a promise, and it is. You're invoking `.catch` on that promise. Nothing you can do can make `then` *not* return a promise, it's part of the implementation of whatever Promise library you're using.  If the library conforms to the spec, `then` will return a promise.

Your callback to `then` does *not* have to return a promise; whatever your callback does or does not return cannot change `then`'s returning of a promise, it will regardless. Your callback *may* return a promise which causes `then` to behave differently, but it will still return a `promise`.

To summarize:

```
.then( //THIS must return a promise, and it's up to the implementation to do so


  function(account) { // THIS (your code) doesn't have to return a promise

      res.send(account);
       //----- then must return a promise here -----
       //       ^ NO, that is wrong
       //
       // We're inside a callback being passed to then, the return value
       // of this function is *not* then's return value
  })
```